# How to alias registers in MIPS32 asm?

Tags: assembly, mips32

Is there a way to rename register in MIPS32 to make it easy to read ?
Something like:

```
    #define $t0 $num_of_rows
    #define $t1 $num_of_cols
    ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a GNU toolchain then it would be:

```
#define num_of_rows $t0
#define num_of_cols $t1
```

Comment: Yes I am using:        
#define num_of_rows  $8